# getting started with Enthought Canopy - pandas not importing?

Tags: python, pandas, canopy

I'm just trying to get started with python following *Python for Data Analysis* but I've been having a really tough time getting everything to line up (this is sad but I am four hours in at least to an attempted install...?!?!). I have an academic license for Enthought Canopy, and I read through this and tried to follow it:

```
http://docs.enthought.com/canopy/quick-start/install_windows.html
```

Problem is that the program never actually asked me to do an Environment Setup, unlike what the docs say. I tried rebooting, restarting the program, and uninstalling/reinstalling several times with no luck. All I want to do is play around with pandas, but package loading is clealy not working.

I am just trying to run this code:

```
import pandas
plot(arrange(10))
```

When I run this, here's my error:

```
import pandas

plot(arrange(10))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f4ad02ce74fb> in <module>()
----> 1 plot(arrange(10))

NameError: name 'arrange' is not defined
```

I am guessing this is somewhat related to some path or environmental variable that should have gotten set, but I'm completely lost to be honest.

Also I found the /Canopy folder in my /User folder. It has two subfolders, licenses and scripts, and both of these folders are completely empty even when I want to see hidden files.

Anyhow, if anyone has any advice or helpful links I'd really appreciate it. All I want to do is start messing around with python, and I've got no ideas how to get to that seemingly basic point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `arrange` is not an existing pandas function, but `arange` is the numpy function you are after. Further, if you do `import pandas`, you have to do `pandas.functionname(..)` to use a function

Comment: Another issue you may have even if you fix your typo for `arrange` you may need to do `import numpy as np np.arange(10)`

Answer (score 0):

I met with the same problem.
You can go to add c:\Python27;c:\Python27\Scripts to your environment variables under system properties of your computer
And it works